# Add the character "%" to counter up

Tags: jquery, html, counter

I need to add the character "%" to the number to which the counter up script is applied. When you add a character, the counter stands still. Thank you very much for your help. 
I tried adding a function at the end of the code, it did not help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('span[data-toggle="counter-up"]').html($('span[data-toggle="counter-up"]').html()+ ' %');
  });
</script>
```

My HTML

```
  <section id="facts"  class="wow fadeIn">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row counters">
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
              <span data-toggle="counter-up">1807</span>
              <p>Единиц техники под нашим сопровождением</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
              <span data-toggle="counter-up">7342</span>
              <p>Пользовательскх обращений решено за 2017 год</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
              <span data-toggle="counter-up">57</span>
              <p>Информационных систем реализовано</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
              <span data-toggle="counter-up">94</span>
              <p>Уровень SLA по решению пользовательских обращений</p>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </section>
```

I use jquery.counterup.js 2.1.0

Comment: Extremely sorry. Forgot to add. I only need the "%" sign for the last value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
  $(function(){
    var el = $('span[data-toggle="counter-up"]');
    var text = el.text();
    // do something with the value
    // append ' %' to the value
    el.text(text + ' %');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using either **CSS** or **JQuery**

**using JQuery**

You need to iterate through each `span[data-toggle="counter-up"]` element and replace its value, else you will only get the first elements value

Try this

```js
$(function(){
    addPercentage();
 });

 function addPercentage(){
    $('span[data-toggle="counter-up"]').each(function(elem){
        $(this).html($(this).html() + " %");
    });
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="facts"  class="wow fadeIn">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row counters">
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
              <span data-toggle="counter-up">1807</span>
              <p>Единиц техники под нашим сопровождением</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
              <span data-toggle="counter-up">7342</span>
              <p>Пользовательскх обращений решено за 2017 год</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
              <span data-toggle="counter-up">57</span>
              <p>Информационных систем реализовано</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
              <span data-toggle="counter-up">94</span>
              <p>Уровень SLA по решению пользовательских обращений</p>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </section>
```

**using CSS**

You can do it directly by css using pseudo class `::after` and `content` property. No need to add jquery or js

```css
span[data-toggle="counter-up"]::after {
  content: " %";
}
```

```html
<section id="facts"  class="wow fadeIn">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row counters">
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
              <span data-toggle="counter-up">1807</span>
              <p>Единиц техники под нашим сопровождением</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
              <span data-toggle="counter-up">7342</span>
              <p>Пользовательскх обращений решено за 2017 год</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
              <span data-toggle="counter-up">57</span>
              <p>Информационных систем реализовано</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
              <span data-toggle="counter-up">94</span>
              <p>Уровень SLA по решению пользовательских обращений</p>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: the counter stands still.

Comment: Is that increments? if so add the script in the answer

Comment: And what you mean still. Does the values update by any other scripts?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Only numbers are counted in the script. The character "%" is counted as a string. Submitted the plugin for revision to another programmer.

Comment: If so, put the logic in a function and call it whenever an update happens

Comment: Answer updated. call the `addPercentage` function after the value updation